# Webpack Code Spliting increases the overall bundle size by 300%

Tags: javascript, webpack, rollup, purescript, code-splitting

For explaining this issue. I have created a sample [project](https://github.com/Adien7368/purescript-dynamic-split-test).
I am using purescript. I am doing a dynamic import and webpack is generating 2 bundles.

If I comment the dynamic import and use a static import, I am getting a bundle size around 12 KB.
But, with dynamic split, webpack is generating 2 bundle, one is of 200 Bytes and other one 29 KB.

I am not sure why 20 KB is getting added in the first bundle after split.

Can someone help me in figuring out, What is increasing the bundle size ?